# Creating and passing a JavaScript Object with parameters/settings/options

Tags: javascript, html, parameters, javascript-objects

I am trying to pass some parameters/settings/options to my external script. These parameters need to be in a script tag that appears in the HTML document. I would like the default settings to be included in the external script but overwritten if the `person` object that is passed has updated settings. Any advice on this would be most appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
// Default settings to be overwritten
var def_person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: "blue"
};

var person = Object.assign({}, def_person, newPerson);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.firstName + " " + person.lastName + ". He is " + person.age + " years old!";

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Will not work if included in head -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Creating and passing a JavaScript Object.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  newPerson = { 
   firstName : 'Mr.',
   lastName : 'Livingston',
   age : 42
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("#demo").person({` is saying you made an extension to jQuery....

Comment: So learn about templating frameworks where you can update the UI when you alter the data.

Comment: @epascarello, thank you for your reply. I am trying to pass updated parameters to my external script so it affects the settings of my JavaScript Object. I'm trying to implement a clean solution kind of like how FancyBox did theirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.assign` or spread operator to merge the values, and pass the input through an exported function.

```js
var def_person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: "blue"
};

function updatePerson(newPerson) {
  var person = Object.assign({}, def_person, newPerson)
  // or {...def_person, ...newPerson}
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.firstName + " " + person.lastName + ". He is " + person.age + " years old!";
}


function init() {
  updatePerson({})
}

// Testing
init()
updatePerson({
  firstName: 'Mr.'
})
```

```html
<div id='demo'></div>
```

## Passing To Script Via A Global

If you want to pass arguments to a script, without calling a function after the script loads, define them as a global in an inline script, and have your external script read them.

In this example, aScript.js will use `newPerson` defined in window.

```
<script>
   newPerson = {firstName:'Mike'}
</script>

<script src='aScript.js'></script>
```

You would then check for `newPerson` in your external script and merge as needed.

Comment: or we can also use the spread operator.
`var person = {...def_person, ...newPerson} console.log(person)`

Comment: @samee This is true, sugar, but still true. Will update answer!

Comment: @StevenSpungin, thank you for your suggestions. I have updated my code with your edits. I see what you are trying to do and that is what I envisioned. However, there seems to be a disconnect between the passing of the updated parameters in the HTML and the accepting of these new parameters in the external JavaScript file. Any more thoughts?

Comment: @Peter You have to set the additional value in your script.  The caveat is that you have to wait for the DOM to load, too.  I will add an init method to show this.

Comment: @Peter I added an init function that sets the default value, and an update function.  Your script can wait for the DOM to load and then call init. And your consumer can call the update function after load as well.

Comment: @StevenSpungin I appreciate your help with this. Your solution works only if the `init` function and `init()` is present inside of script.js. How would I go about implementing a FancyBox-like solution where I just pass the new parameters to my external script?

Comment: @Peter You can define your parameter in window before loading the script, and have script use that.  I will post at end of my solution.

Comment: @StevenSpungin, what do you mean by `newPerson` will be defined in `window`?

Comment: @Peter After your inline script declares newPerson, you external script can access it by `newPerson` or `window.newPerson`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe through `window` object?

```
window.person = {
    firstName:"John",
    lastName:"Doe",
    age:50,
    eyeColor:"blue"
};
```

**window** is global object for your current browser tab, so you can pass something through it. But it is kind of hacky solution.

Then you can read that via `window.person`